# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) %20

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm building a .Net MVC web app.  When I load the website, the site loads just fine but takes kinda long and gives a javascript error in the console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  %20

The '%20' corresponds to `http://localhost:####/%20`.

This looks like the app is trying to load a page that just has a space in it's name but doesn't find it, so it just loads the index instead.  If anybody knows why this is happening and how to fix it, that would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: What do your mvc routes look like?

Comment: It compiles, which takes the time, then it tries to find a page called %20.  The question is *why the heck are you browsing to /%20?* What triggers this?  You're not telling us how or where that resource is being loaded.

Comment: @Will my question is where is that resource being loaded.  I am not trying to browse to /%20, It just is doing it.  I need to know how to fix that.

Comment: You have some code that loads a malformed URL.  Without seeing your code that's as far as it can go.  Post code!

Comment: @James I cannot post code for NDA reasons. I just need to know where this malformed URL might be and what it might look like.  This is happening when I first load the home page and the home page contains an MVC grid view and a hidden popup